# Ubuntu 13.10 not booting

Tags: installation, boot, 13.10

I cannot start Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop! I burned 2 cds and made a bootable pendrive but when i reboot my pc it start Windows 7, but when i try to boot Ubuntu 13.04 it starts normally.

Sorry for the grammar errors, i'm not a native speaker.

Edit: I'm using the 64bit version

Comment: I think the problem is different, i can't even boot from CD!

Comment: Could you edit your question and explain why you cannot boot from CD/USB? Did you change the boot order? Please be as verbose and detailed as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Before all, can you complete your profile, its more friendly and we can answer with more enphasys!

May be you dont configure your BIOS to boot from CD/USB.
Actually there is a lot of version of BIOS, and In each one, there is different ways to get in to change your config.

Try this:

When you power-on your PC, the first screen/image that you can see is about motherboard (before windows logo), when this appear, you can press some of this keys to get in Setup mode:

F2, F4, F8, Delete key  when LOGO or Info system appear to enter in setup.
In some BIOS, you can read some info about keys near to buttom or may be upper in left side.

F12 or F10 in some system let you select BOOTING media. (A list, to Select you booting drive)

If you can GET IN, you must search in menu only "BOOTING SECUENCE" or "BOOTING DRIVE" or similar stuff...

Let be first USB/CD (some can change with +/- key another with page up/down or with cursor keys).

Read at buttom there is info about key and How can you save all change. Take care with configuration changed, I recomends you write every parameter changed. 
Often you can save that pressing F10 and accept.

**-EDIT-**

**I see, so, May be your Grub its not working anymore, so you need download a tool to recover it, and reinstall it.
You can try in Windows, downloading Wingrub, you can follow all instructions from here: http://members.iinet.net.au/~herman546/p9.html

Tell me if you resolve your problem!

Bye.

Comment: I have tried this, but i can't enter in my bios anymore. But there is no problem with the boot sequence since i can start Ubuntu 13.04 with no problems. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: @Anonymous What? Don't you have *any* problem any more? Can you enter your BIOS, boot from external devices and any installed OS? How did you solved this?

Comment: @Lucio No, the problem is that i cannot boot Ubuntu 13.10 but the 13.04 boots fine!

Comment: Then you will need to enter to your BIOS or another way to change the boot order to run an Ubuntu's Live version. Try pressing some `FN` key or read the motherboards' manual.